# Customise C++ Language Mode (VSCode)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In VSCode, I am using a programming language which has similarities to C++, however there are a few differences that cause issues when a file is formatted. The syntax highlighting is great.

The main difference is the use of the `private` keyword. The formatter changes `private variable sql;` (one-line) to the following multi-line statement:

```cpp
    private
        variable sql;
```

Is there a way to get the language mode files for c++ so I can modify them and create a new language, or is there a better way to prevent this?

Comment: The syntax without the `:` after `private` is more like C# or Java than C++. How close to C++ is your language otherwise? Perhaps using a C# or Java formatter or highlighter might be closer to your actual syntax?

Comment: And it shouldn't be too hard to find the location of the standard C++ (or C# / Java) syntax definition files for VSCode, and copy it for you own language to modify. Also see e.g. [the VSCode language extensions documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/api/language-extensions/overview).

Comment: what extension are you using to do the formatting, and what relevant configuration have you set?

Comment: Thanks both. I was just using the default Microsoft C/C++ extension. It's a kind of mongrel language, and has aspects of both Some Programmer Dude. I've tried to find the language syntax definition files but to no avail. I'll keep in looking for them though!